# Find users who has not invited any user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find those users who has not invited any user by a single query (using aggregate).

for Example : I have 4 users in DB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87a"),
    "name": "aaa",
    "invitedBy": ObjectId("5808f53d28c14ee470856d8b")
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87b"),
    "name": "bbb",
    "invitedBy": ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87a")
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87c"),
    "name": "ccc",
    "invitedBy": ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87a"),
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87d"),
    "name": "ddd",
    "invitedBy": ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87b"),
}
```

Here

> 1- aaa invited bbb and ccc  user
>
> 2- bbb invited ddd user
>
> 3- but ccc and ddd user not invited any one

so I want to pic **ccc** and **ddd** users

it would be better if can by using aggregate because I need perform some operation on selected data.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: MongoDB version is 3.2 @Styvane

Comment: @4J41 Please do not use the [`mongodb-aggregation` tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337096/let-burninate-mongodb-aggregation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator to perform a left join to the collection itself.

*The users who have not sent any invitation* are those with empty invitation array. To retrieve only those users, simply filter the documents in a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match) stage using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator and numeric array indexing.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        { "$lookup": { 
            "from": "users", 
            "localField": "_id", 
            "foreignField": "invitedBy", 
            "as": "invitation"
        }}, 
        { "$match": { "invitation.0": { "$exists": false } } }
    ]
)
```

which yields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87c"),
    "name" : "ccc",
    "invitedBy" : ObjectId("581a18d41b6c5c752f11c87a"),
    "invitation" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87d"),
    "name" : "ddd",
    "invitedBy" : ObjectId("581a1a671b6c5c752f11c87b"),
    "invitation" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another method to do the same. But this method might end up being less efficient than @Styvane's answer. This should work if there are lesser elements.

```
[
 {$group: {_id: null, senders: {$addToSet: '$invitedBy'}, everyone: {$addToSet: '$_id'}}},
 {$project: {_id: 0, res: {$setDifference: ['$everyone', '$senders']}}}
]
```

In case other information is needed, that can also be obtained (sorry but it becomes bit dirty here)

```
[
     {$group: {_id: null, senders: {$addToSet: '$invitedBy'}, everyone: {$addToSet: {id: '$_id', name: '$name'}}}},
     {$project: {_id: 0, everyone: 1, res: {$setDifference: ['$everyone.id', '$senders']}}},
     {$unwind: '$everyone'},
     {$unwind: '$res'},
     {$project: {flag: {$eq: ['$everyone.id', '$res']}, everyone: 1}},
     {$match: {flag: true}}
]
```

Comment: What if OP needs to retrieve all the fields in the documents not just the `_id` field?