# MongoDB find all not in this array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to find all users except for a few, like this:

```
// get special user IDs
var special = db.special.find({}, { _id: 1 }).toArray();

// get all users except for the special ones
var users = db.users.find({_id: {$nin: special}});
```

This doesn't work because the array that I'm passing to `$nin` is not and array of `ObjectId` but an array of `{ _id: ObjectId() }`

Variable `special` looks like this after the first query:

```
[ { _id: ObjectId(###) }, { _id: ObjectId(###) } ]
```

But `$nin` in the second query needs this:

```
[ ObjectId(###), ObjectId(###) ]
```

**How can I get just the `ObjectId()` in an array** from the first query so that I can use them in the second query?

Or, is there a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find users who has not invited any user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626075/find-users-who-has-not-invited-any-user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`cursor.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.map/)** method returned by the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** function to transform the list of `{ _id: ObjectId(###) }` documents to an array of **`ObjectId`**'s as in the following

```
var special = db.special.find({}, { _id: 1 }).map(function(doc){
    return doc._id;
});
```

---

Another approach you can consider is using the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator in the aggregation framework to do a "left outer join" on the `special` collection and filtering the documents on the new "joined" array field. The filter should match on documents whose array field is empty.

The following example demonstrates this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "special",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "specialUsers" // <-- this will produce an arry of "joined" docs
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "specialUsers.0": { "$exists": false } } } // <-- match on empty array
])
```

Comment: Turns out you can even use arrow functions - .map(doc => doc._id)

Comment: @felix Thanks for noticing the typo

Comment: @17xande Indeed, since with MongoDB 3.2, the javascript engine used for both the mongo shell and for server-side javascript in mongod changed from V8 to SpiderMonkey thus it has support for features like arrow-functions, destructuring assignment, for-of loops, and generators

Comment: @17xande you don't even need arrow function. how about `let special = db.special.distinct('_id')`?

Comment: @Styvane Interesting approach. Wouldn't that introduce extra overhead on a large set of documents since it would have to double check for unique values? In this case the values would all be unique since they're IDs, but I assume it would still do that check anyway?

Comment: @17xande [`_id` are always unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/glossary/#term-id).